# White stuff on the top of my apple cider vinegar?

Tags: food-safety, vinegar, mold

This white stuff has appeared on my Apple cider vinegar. Is it good or do I remove it?

It has been 4 weeks. I was going to strain the apples out today and let it sit for another 4 weeks.

Smell of the vinegar is nice and doesn't have a bad odour.

[image: photograph of apple cider vinegar (side view)]
[image: photograph of apple cider vinegar (top view)]

Answer (score 5):

That is mold. You should skim it off and throw it away. It's probably an indication that your acid to sugar balance is not correct. If it comes back I'd throw away your batch and try again.

Answer (score -2):

Mold and the white film are two separate things! If it’s actually mold then you probably don’t want the batch but the white stuff is a penicillium similar to what covers Brie or end up on top of KimChee and other ferments. It’s part of fermentation and is not goi g to ruin a batch. I would research more before trusting blogs to tell you what’s up with your ferments - sometimes opinions are not sound advice. Just a word of advice

Comment: Penicillium is a genus of mold, and while it is part of the production of certain foods (e.g., *Penicillium camemberti* is the penicillium species for Brie), there's no guarantee the mold here is 1) safe 2) or even a penicillium species. For example, the white colonies you may find on kimchi come from yeast genera, not penicillium.